Nodemailer - Yahoo SMTP - replyTo breaking
When I try to include a 'replyTo' address in the Nodemailer mail config object that's anything other than the same address as the 'from' address I get the the following error: '550 Request failed; Mailbox unavailable'. Example:
this works:
const mail = {
  subject: name,
  from: emailA,
  replyTo: emailA,
  to: receiver,
  text: content
}

this does not:
const mail = {
  subject: name,
  from: emailA,
  replyTo: emailB,
  to: receiver,
  text: content
}

My assumption is that this is a Yahoo problem rather than a Nodemailer problem, but I've not found a solution yet and any help would be greatly appreciated.
